# Is it possible to host an app on live.com?

Tags: web-applications, hosting

I was asked to build a web app with the following restrictions:

1) As the client doesn't have the infrastructure required, the web app has to be hosted on the cloud.

2) The hosting has to be free or very low cost.

3) Have similar services to live.com (suscribe to public calendars, log in using your hotmail account, so on...).

I also was told that it was possible to host my web app at live.com or live.edu, but didn't find anything like that searching in the web.

I leave you these two links that were all that I could find about live.com and live.edu.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/default

http://www.microsoft.com/liveatedu/

Greetings, Diego.

Comment: Sorry, questions about free hosting are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. I'm a new user. Where can I read that rules?

Comment: The [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/)  from google is a low cost/free hosting service for your need in this case.You can use google calendar and gmail for your 3rd requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the quickly response! I also investigated app engine and I think it could be a possible solution... But do you know if it's possible to host a web app at live.com?

Comment: live is not equivalent to appEngine.Its equivalent to gmail for custom domain.i.e. you will get you@yourdomain.com mail id but actually mailbox and other things is in live network.But you cant upload your custom code/app there